# oracle order by date clause in apex tabular form

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-order-by, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I have an oracle apex tabular form with following region query

```
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE, 
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null ,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT 
   from dual 
                             union 
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,DIV_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,CREDIT,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT
   from DIVIDENT_REG
   where code=:MCODE and memno=:MEMNO and brcode=:BRCODE
   order by  DIV_DATE desc
```

I want the result in discending order of column DIV_DATE.  But the above order by clause does not work. So I used the code

```
order by to_date(DIV_DATE) desc
```

But it shows an error

> ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

**EDIT :** I can not choose

```
select div_date,credit from(    
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE, 
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null ,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT 
   from dual 
                             union 
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,DIV_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,CREDIT,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT
   from DIVIDENT_REG
   where code=:MCODE and memno=:MEMNO and brcode=:BRCODE
   order by  DIV_DATE desc    )
```

since it will drop properties of my apex_item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would any of these options help?

First, `ORDER BY 1 DESC`, where "1" represents the first column returned by a query:

```
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE, 
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null ,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT 
from dual 
union 
select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,DIV_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,CREDIT,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT
from DIVIDENT_REG
where code=:MCODE and memno=:MEMNO and brcode=:BRCODE
order by 1 desc;
```

Or, using your "original" query as an inline view, and then "normally" order by DIV_DATE:

```
select div_date, credit
from (select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE, 
             APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null ,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT 
      from dual 
      union 
      select APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(1,DIV_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
             APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,CREDIT,10,15,'style="width:100px;text-align:right"') CREDIT
      from DIVIDENT_REG
      where code=:MCODE and memno=:MEMNO and brcode=:BRCODE
     )
order by div_date desc;
```

Comment: order I can not choose this query since it will drop properties of apex_item

Comment: "ORDER BY 1 DESC" works for me; I've just tried it on apex.oracle.com (Apex 5.1.3); which version do you use?

Comment: I hope everything is fine with you; it's just your tabular form that is stubborn :) How did you create that page? Try to create it once again, from scratch, so that it wouldn't contain any additional settings. Then, if you make it work, add whatever you find appropriate. Test frequently so that you could revert changes, if necessary.

Comment: Ok.. let me try once more. Currently I'm getting result in a descending order of date string which is converted into a character type.

Comment: Aha. In that case, include additional column into SELECT: SYSDATE (with alias DIV_DATE) in the first one, DIV_DATE in the second one. Choose **NOT** to display them (set them to be HIDDEN), Then ORDER BY DIV_DATE DESC - that should be OK, as long as DIVIDENT_REG.DIV_DATE column is of a DATE datatype.

Comment: oh my god.. Thanks a lot.. :) <3

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT   TB.*
    FROM (SELECT APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2 (1,
                                        SYSDATE,
                                        'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
                 APEX_ITEM.TEXT (2,
                                 NULL,
                                 10,
                                 15,
                                 'style="width:100px;text-align:right"')
                                                                       CREDIT
            FROM DUAL
          UNION
          SELECT APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2 (1,
                                        DIV_DATE,
                                        'DD-MM-YYYY') DIV_DATE,
                 APEX_ITEM.TEXT (2,
                                 CREDIT,
                                 10,
                                 15,
                                 'style="width:100px;text-align:right"')
                                                                       CREDIT
            FROM DIVIDENT_REG
           WHERE CODE = :MCODE
                 AND MEMNO = :MEMNO
                 AND BRCODE = :BRCODE) TB
ORDER BY TB.DIV_DATE DESC
```

Comment: order by 1 does not works. I can not choose second query since it will drop properties of apex_item

Comment: @Nidheesh `I didnot suggested for Order by 1`. You can tell if what i posted is working or not

Comment: sorry XING , my mistake. I can not choose second query since it will drop properties of apex_item

Comment: @Nidheesh Did you try that or its your assumption. Ideally the query you posted should had worked fine in your case. Not sure why its not working for you.

Comment: I tried this,I just copied this in my page and the result is - the date string got converted into a character type and sorted this in descending order of character date string.

Comment: Thank you for the helps @XING